# Rock Paper Scissors and the one mysterious response error

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom-events

I am currently working on my rock paper scissors game. Specifically, I'm working on `eventListeners` and making sure that when someone clicks a "rock" button, a function is triggered for the computer to randomly pick either rock, paper, or scissors and then creates a new paragraph inside a container with a concatenated response such as "You win, paper beats rock". All but one of my responses are working.

`let results = playerWin + rockWin;` is the only response that is for some reason not working. It should say "You win, rock beats scissors." Instead, it is going back and saying it was a tie. I have `console.log`ged to see if this was occurring without the `eventlistener` attached. For some reason it works out, but when i want it to print when triggered, it just isn't working. Can you help me find what I'm missing? I definitely can provide more of my code if the issue isn't within the code that I have. I just didn't want to clog my post with unrelated code.

```
const options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
const rock = options[0];
const paper = options[1];
const scissors = options[2];
const rockWin = "Rock beats scissors.";
const paperWin = "Paper beats rock.";
const scissorsWin = "Scissors beats paper";
const tie = "It was a tie";
const playerWin = "You won! ";
const computerWin = "You lose! ";
const oops = "Please try again";
let computerPoints = 0;
let playerPoints = 0;

//eventListeners to html

const btn = document.querySelectorAll('btn');
const rockbtn = document.querySelector('#rockbtn');
const paperbtn = document.querySelector('#paperbtn');
const scissorsbtn = document.querySelector('#scissorsbtn');
const resultContainer = document.querySelector('#resultContainer')
const resultPara = document.querySelector('#resultPara')
//Computer's choice

function computerPlay(){
let compChoice = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
return compChoice;
}


//One round of the game
    function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection){
        if (playerSelection === computerSelection){
            let results = tie;
            resultPara.textContent = results;
            console.log(playerSelection,playerPoints);
            console.log(computerSelection, computerPoints);
            return tie;
        }

        else if(playerSelection === rock && computerSelection === paper){
            computerPoints = computerPoints + 1;
            let results = computerWin + paperWin;
            resultPara.textContent = results;
            console.log(playerSelection,playerPoints);
            console.log(computerSelection,computerPoints);
            return computerWin + paperWin;
        }

        else if(playerSelection === rock && computerSelection === scissors){
            playerPoints = playerPoints + 1;
            let results = playerWin + rockWin;
            console.log(playerSelection,playerPoints);
            console.log(computerSelection,computerPoints);
            return playerWin + rockWin;
```

Further down I have my eventlisteners.

```
paperbtn.addEventListener('click', paperPlay);
scissorsbtn.addEventListener('click', scissorsPlay);

function rockPlay(){
    playRound(rock, computerPlay());
}


function paperPlay(){
    playRound(paper, computerPlay());
}
function scissorsPlay(){
    playRound(scissors, computerPlay());
}
```

Comment: you've ignore several possible combinations

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why it is saying it's a tie. You did forget to put combos for `playerSelection === paper`, but I don't think that's where your specified issue comes from. In the included event listeners you forgot one for rock, which should be `rockbtn.addEventListener('click', rockPlay)`. I don't know if any of these will help solve your problem, but they are things I noticed after looking at what you provided.
Below I have your `if/else if` chain which you are using to determine the results. I added in combos for `playerSelection === paper`, and I put any other notes I could think of.
I hope this helps in some way!

```
if (playerSelection === computerSelection){
            let results = tie;
            resultPara.textContent = results;
            console.log(playerSelection,playerPoints);
            console.log(computerSelection, computerPoints);
            return tie;
        }

        else if(playerSelection === rock && computerSelection === paper){
            computerPoints += 1;
            let results = computerWin + paperWin;
            resultPara.textContent = results;
            console.log(playerSelection,playerPoints);
            console.log(computerSelection,computerPoints);
            return results; // use results variable because you can
        }

        else if(playerSelection === rock && computerSelection === scissors){
            playerPoints += 1; // I recommend using the += operator for this
            let results = playerWin + rockWin;
            console.log(playerSelection,playerPoints);
            console.log(computerSelection,computerPoints);
            return results;

        // adding the combos where playerSelection == paper
        
        else if(playerSelection === paper && computerSelection === rock){
            playerPoints += 1; 
            let results = playerWin + paperWin;
            console.log(playerSelection,playerPoints);
            console.log(computerSelection,computerPoints);
            return results;

        else if(playerSelection === paper && computerSelection === scissors){
            computerPoints += 1;
            let results = computerWin + rockWin;
            console.log(playerSelection,playerPoints);
            console.log(computerSelection,computerPoints);
            return results;
```